# ffmpeg concat of multiple files audio out of sync

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to concatenate multiple files together using ffmpeg concatenate demuxer. However final video is out of sync.

First parts are coming from static image which are converted to 5-seconds video in the following way:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -i 1.png -vf loop=loop=150:size=1:start=0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -tune stillimage loop.mp4
```

Then I add silent audio stream:

```
ffmpeg -i loop.mp4 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -map 0:v -map 1:a -ar 44100 -ac 2 -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest silent.mp4
```

ffrobe for the silent.mp4:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries stream=start_time,duration silent.mp4
[STREAM]
start_time=0.000000
duration=5.733333
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
start_time=0.000000
duration=5.665011
[/STREAM]
```

Which already shows that audio and video streams have different duration.

Then I prepare concat input file, last line is the video with same dimension and framerate, also it has existing audio stream (44.1kHz, stereo)

```
file silent.mp4
file silent.mp4
... (multiple lines, say 10)
file silent.mp4
file video.mp4
```

To make sure that inputs have same parameters:

```
ffmpeg -i silent.mp4 -i video.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'silent.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 19 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:43.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1622 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 1484 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Now, after concatenation final video is out of sync with audio (audio stream of the last part starts before static part is finished)

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy result.mp4 (no warnings)
```

I have tried to pad audio stream with silence in both loop.mp4 and video.mp4, but it did not help  - it randomly modifies duration and start time of both video and audio streams and audio is again out of sync after concat.

Also, I am not able to increase the duration of static part (so that number of entries in concat.txt can be decreased) because each static part can be different - this is just an example.

Comment: Verify that all inputs have all of the same attributes.

Comment: @llogan as I mentioned - dimension and framerate are the same. Is there any other particular attribute that should be same? Demuxer documentation is quite vague unfortunately.

Comment: Video: format, profile, width, height, pixel format, timebase. Audio: format, profile, channel layout, sample rate, sample format. Also need same number and same type of streams.

Comment: @llogan unfortunately that does not help. Only way I managed to get result without sync issues is concat filter but in some other cases it works too slow.

Comment: Show info on all the inputs if you want me to check attributes. The complete output of `ffmpeg -n -i input0 -i input1 -i input2`, etc will suffice. Ignore the `At least one output file must be specified` error: this command is only to get info on your `ffmpeg` and the files.

Comment: @llogan thank you, I updated question with the input attributes information.

Comment: I can't duplicate the issue, and I see no file differences. Try `ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -i 1.png -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -t 5 silent2.mp4`